Generalization of Connes metric on state space
Let  we  have  a spectral triples $(A,H,D)$
The  Connes  distance on the  space of states of $A$ is the following:
$$d(\phi,\psi)=sup_{ |[D,a]|\leq 1}   |\phi(a)-\psi(a)|\quad (*)$$
Is this metric equivalent to the  same  metric  but  with the extra constraint $|[D,[D,a]]|\leq 1$
For  1 dimensional Riemannian  manifold they are the same.
As a possible related question:
What about the following (possible)  distance:
$$\tilde{d}(\phi,\psi)=sup_{[D,a]=1} |\phi(a)-\psi(a)|$$
Under what  condition is $\tilde{d}$ a metric?Under what condition is that equivalent to  the Connes metric?
In 1 dimensional  manifold it is the the original metric.
About tags: The  motivation for  Connes distance in $(*)$ is that: for  dirac operator the formula gives the  standard Riemannian distance. This is the reason of tags  DG and  RG
